# Spring Webflux CSP not taking affect in React website

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-webflux, content-security-policy

Hey Stackoverflow geniuses. I have a problem that is causing me some trouble that I am hoping you can help me out with. I have defined a Content Security Policy in my server code which uses Spring Boot Webflux. The CSP is being sent up to the client and can be seen in the Response Headers. However, the CSP does not appear to be getting applied to the site. This is the configuration:

```
/* http is a ServerHttpSecurity object */
http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self';" +
"media-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; worker-src 'none'; form-action 'self';" +
"frame-src 'none'; child-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';")
.and()
.frameOptions().mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.DENY);
```

and this is what I see in my response headers:

```
ache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self';media-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; worker-src 'none'; form-action 'self';frame-src 'none'; child-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';
content-type: application/json
Date: Mon, 30 Aug 2021 16:33:28 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
referrer-policy: no-referrer
transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
X-Powered-By: Express
x-xss-protection: 1 ; mode=block
```

A couple of these setting when applied should block my site from being loaded in an i-frame but even with the header containing these values, an i-frame can still load it. Also, I am able to inject unsafe scripts and styles.

I am testing in the most recent version of Chrome. The fact that I see the CSP in my response headers but it doesn't block these security risks tells me I'm missing something. Is there a step I need to take to apply the CSP to the front end when it receives the response? Again, this is a React front end and a Java/Spring Boot back end. Just in case this matters, the front end and back end are separate projects.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that no plugins like Noscript, [Disable Content-Security-Policy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden), etc. are installed in the browser.

There is no difference what software you use on the frontend and on the backend - the browser doesn't know anything about the backend, it just gets an HTML page with HTTP headers and renders it. If the browser has received a CSP HTTP header, it will apply it.

The CSP you show (line breaks added for readability):

```
default-src 'self';
script-src 'self';
img-src 'self';
media-src 'self';
object-src 'self';
connect-src 'self';
worker-src 'none';
form-action 'self';
frame-src 'none';
child-src none;
style-src 'self';
frame-ancestors 'none';
```

abundantly clear disallows embedding into iframe (by `frame-ancestors 'none';`), inline styles (by `style-src 'self';`) and inline scripts (by `script-src 'self';`). There is one syntax error: `child-src none;` the `'none'` should be single-quoted, but this does not matter in this case.

To make sure of this, it is enough to create an HTML page with your CSP:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self';
  img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; worker-src 'none';
  form-action 'self'; frame-src 'none'; child-src none; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';">
</head>
<body>
<div style='color:red' onclick='alert("clicked!")'>is is red? Click me!</div>
</body>
```

and open it in a browser with the console (Dev Tool) enabled. You will see the blocked inline styles and the script.

Meta tag works the exactly same way as HTTP header just `frame-ancestors` directive is not supported in meta tag.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for pointing out the one syntax error. I have fixed that.

The browser I am testing in doesn't have any plugins that should disable the CSP. I have already tested the CSP when placed directly in the html in a meta tag. It works fine there. It just doesn't seem to get applied when supplied in the Response Headers.

Comment: Meta tag works exactly as HTTP header. To verify that the CSP HTTP header applied, make a policy: `http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'bad_token';");` and you should see: `The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: ''bad_token''. It will be ignored.` in the Chrome console.